# How to automatically call a (browser) Client from a Twilio Conference Call?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twilio

Here is the scenario:

Assume we have a client with a capability to allow incoming calls, named "Roger".

James calls our Twilio number

```
  conferenceName = "conftest"
  caller_id = "+15555555555"
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial :callerId => caller_id do |d|
      d.Client 'Roger'
    end
  end
```

Now we want Roger to get the incoming call on his browser, but we want the call to be a conference call, rather than a phone-to-browser call (not sure if there is a technical name for this). How can I connect James to Roger in a conference call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Sadly, this is not as simple as a single TwiML response. What you need to do is drop James into a conference call and, at the same time, initiate a call to Roger's client, which on answering would drop him into the conference call too.

With code (in a pseudo-sinatra format) that would look like:

```
conference_name = "conftest"
caller_id = "+15555555555"

# Set the Twilio number endpoint URL to /dial, this will drop James into 
# the conference and initiate the call to Roger.
post '/dial' do
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial do |d|
      d.Conference conference_name
    end
  end
  # create a REST API client with your Account SID and Auth token
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new "AC123...", "XYZ456..."
  client.calls.create from: caller_id, to: "Roger", url: "/client_dial"
  response.to_xml
end

# This endpoint is the one that Twilio will hit when Roger answers the 
# client incoming call. All we need to do is drop him into the same 
# conference call.
post "/client_dial" do
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial do |d|
      d.Conference conference_name
    end
  end
  response.to_xml
end
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: yep! wish I had seen this earlier. Spent the night coming up with an identical solution :P

Comment: Ha! Sorry it took me a while to answer! Glad you're all sorted.